# Add & delete note in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, model-view-controller, addition

I am new at AngularJS and I am trying to figure out how to add and delete notes to the setup that I have created. I have tried a lot of different things but I cant figure out how to get it to work.
I have cleaned up my code so it should be easier to figure out.
Please take a look at the [jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/966/) or snippet of my code:

```js
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.sortable']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var i;
  $scope.itemsList = {
    items1: [],
    items2: []
  };

  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i += 1) {
    $scope.itemsList.items1.push({
      'Id': i,
      'Label': 'Item ' + i
    });
  }
  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    containment: '#sortable-container',
    accept: function(sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {
      return sourceItemHandleScope.itemScope.sortableScope.$id === destSortableScope.$id;
    }
  };

});
```

```css
.as-sortable-item,
.as-sortable-placeholder {} #sortable-container {} .touch-mover {
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>

  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/a5hik/ng-sortable/master/dist/ng-sortable.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="sortable-container">
    <div class="form-actions">
      <div class="input-append">
        <form>
          <input class="span3" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Add a note">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-disabled="" ng-click="">
            Add Note
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sortable-row" as-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="itemsList.items1">
      <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList.items1" class="simpel-fighter-input" as-sortable-item>
        <input class="category-form textboxid" type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.Label" placeholder="Deltager1">
        <div as-sortable-item-handle class="touch-mover">MOVE ME</div>
        <a ng-click="" href>
          <div class="touch-mover">DELETE</div>
        </a>
        <input class="category-form textboxid" style="float:right" type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.Label2" placeholder="Deltager2">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **adding** a note just insert into your controller MainCtrl this function:

```
$scope.addNote = function() {
    $scope.itemsList.items1.push({"Id" :  $scope.itemsList.items1.length, "Label": "Item " + $scope.itemsList.items1.length})
}
```

and edit your form (add ng-model to input and ng-click function to button) like:

```
<input class="span3" size="16" type="text" ng-model="noteText" placeholder="Add a note">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-disabled="" ng-click="addNote()">
   Add Note
</button>
```

For **deleting** use in you controller something like

```
$scope.deleteNote = function(index) {
    $scope.itemsList.items1.splice(index,1)
}
```

and attach this function to the  tag "DELETE" like

```
ng-click="deleteNote($index)"
```

I hope this helps.